# how to get props from another component and make it available to the app

Tags: reactjs

how to get the render props from a component and use it in useEffect. In order to make an api call that prop is required . 
So what would be the best way to handle this scenario?

```
const test = () => {
useEffect(() => {
prop1("api call url and input to be given here" )

},[dependencies])
return (
    <div>

    <input ></input>
    <input></input>
        <component>
        {({ prop1, prop2, prop3 }) =>  {

        }}
        </component>         
    </div>
);
};
export default test;
```

Comment: Props are passed to `test` as arguments, can't you get them from there?

Comment: getting the prop as  undefined that way .

Answer (score 0):

add props as the parameter in the test const 
to or make distracter fro the props as {}

```
const test = (props) => {
//what should be do
}
```

to use props used props. attribute

Comment: I destructed the props and logged that prop , receiving that as undefined.

Comment: are you pass this props from the parent as  <test attrubiter={} /> where the component test is used

Comment: no actually I have it ,inside the test component, but to the test component there are other props being passed . how can I send these props along with those ? I did try sending it directly but, it complained saying undefined ,these are render props ,can we send them just like the component props ?